# Cannot define global object in new tab when reused (window.open)

Tags: javascript, tabs, window.open

I'm trying to open a new tab and define an object in its global context (CORS safe), and then reuse the new tab (e.g. refresh) and declare the object in the global context again.

Is there a way to consistently modify the new tab's global variables when the tab is reused?

The first time I run the code below (i.e. opened as a NEW tab) it works as expected and `window.something` is defined in the child tab context.

```
// In parent/main tab.
const newTab = window.open('https://same-domain-url.com', 'knownString');
newTab.something = { dev: true };
```

If I call the same action again, the child tab is refreshed as expected (browser tab reused due to the `target` value - [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#reuse_existing_windows_and_avoid_target_blank)) **but this time `window.something` is not defined in the child context**.

I've determined it's not a race-condition problem because I placed a `console.log(window.something)` within a `setInterval` in the child page JS (at `DOMContentLoaded` event).

I tested the code in Chrome 109.0.5414.87 and Firefox 107.0.1 (64-bit). Exact same behavior in both.

**Edit: Posting some code as example:**

Page 1 (main page @ localhost:8080/page-1):

```
<button id="button">Open Tab</button>
```

```
(function () {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (_) => {
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", (_) => {
      let newTab = window.open(
        "localhost:8080/page-2",
        "page2"
      );
      newTab.something = { dev: true };
    });
  });
})();
```

Page 2 (child page / new tab @ localhost:8080/page-2):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log('>>>>>>', JSON.stringify(window.something));
  }, 1000);
});
```

1. Click on Page 1 button and child tab is created. In child tab's Console you'll see the object correctly.
2. Switch back to the Page 1 tab without closing the child tab. Click on the Page 1 button again. The child tab is refreshed but this time the Console shows the object as `undefined`.

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is there any error in the console on the page 1 tab?

Comment: No, there's no error or warning.